# Laravel 5 sorting by most count child record

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have two tables Quiz and quiz_results.

```
so Quiz hasMany('App\QuizResult')
and QuizResult belongsTo('App\Quiz')
```

In my controller I can query

`$top_quiz = Quiz::with('quiz_results')->limit(10)->get();`

And in my view I can do this

```
{{ $top_quiz->quiz_results()->count() }}
```

This will display the total number of records in quiz_result that belongs to quiz.

Example

```
quiz_id | quiz_result_count (this is the total # of quiz_result of quiz table, this i want to sort)
1       |   3
2       |   2
3       |   3
4       |   5
```

> **The problem is How will I orderBy or sort by $top_quiz->quiz_results()->count()?**

Comment: Didnt get exactly what you want.?

Comment: You can sort the quiz results using the collection methods: $top_quiz->quiz_results()->sort()

Comment: I want to sort the result of  $top_quiz->quiz_results()->count()...which mean count the total # of records in the quiz_result then sort to the most record count

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: @JilsonThomas pls see example... as you can see, the quiz_result_count is populated using eloquent $top_quiz->quiz_results()->count().

Comment: Quiz::with('quiz_results' => function($query){ $query->count();  })->limit(10)->get()->sortBy('quiz_result')->all(); try this. Didnt test though. I'm on mobile

Comment: you got it, you can change your answer will mark it correct...but you need to encapsulate the array with (['quiz_results' => function($query){ $query->count(); }]) in order to work...thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sort the quiz results:

```
Quiz::with(['quiz_results' => function($query) { $query->count(); }])->get()->take(10)->sortBy('quiz_results')->all();
```

Comment: btw since this is collection, ->limit(10) will not get the sorted collection, it should be ->take(10) after the ->get().. thanks

Answer (score 1):

The docs is your friend.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset

`$top_quiz = Quiz::with('quiz_results')->orderBy('grade', 'desc')->limit(10)->get();`